# Laravel get only needed columns from relationship object

Tags: laravel, eloquent, relationship, laravel-5.8, laravel-collection

I have 2 post types:

- Company
- Vacancy

Here I'll get only needed columns after fetching post by type:

```
$posts = $posts->map(function($post) use ($company, $vacancy) {
    switch ($post->type) {
        case $company:
            return $post->only([
                'id',
                'name',
                'slogan',
                'logo'
            ]);
            break;
        case $vacancy:
            return $post->only([
                'id',
                'title',
                'price',
                'schedule',
                'employment',
                'company'
            ]);
            break;
    }
});
```

As you see `vacancy` post type need to `company` column which is relationship object and `company` post type need only to columns:

- 'id'
- 'name'
- 'slogan'
- 'logo'

But when I request `vacancy` post type with `company` relationship object then `company` post type returned with all columns instead of needed column only.

How can be solved my problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can define models for `Company` and `Vacancy`

```
class Company extends Post {
    protected $table = 'posts';

    protected static function boot()
    {
        parent::boot();
        static::addGlobalScope(function ($query) {
            $query->where('type', 'company');
        });
    }
}

class Vacancy extends Post {
    protected $table = 'posts';

    protected static function boot()
    {
        parent::boot();
        static::addGlobalScope(function ($query) {
            $query->where('type', 'vacancy');
        });
    }
}
```

In a project I managed this using a pivot table to store the relationships between the two type of models (I used `BelongsToMany`, but I think you can specify a `HasOne` as well

Comment: I've one model `Post` where will be stored any post types. I have also model `PostType` where defined post types. I can't create model for each post type @Leonardo Rossi

Comment: [Here](https://3v4l.org/jKli1) I solved my problem using `array_intersect_key` php function

Comment: You said you had only 2 post types, you could treat them as separate models (even though storing them in `posts` table). Anyway glad you found a solution :)